# why I can call parent method without super keyword?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I learn java inheritance, and this is my parent and child class

```
public class ParentClass {
  String name;
  final String subject = "Java";

  public ParentClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  void intro () {
    System.out.println("Learn " + this.subject);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  ChildClass(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  void getMethodParent() {
    intro();
    System.out.println(subject);
  }
}
```

my question is why i can still access method or variable from parent class without using super keyword? like method **intro** in **getMethodParent**, it should be **super.intro()**.

I use:

1. jdk 17.0.1
2. Visual studio code

Comment: In really simple terms (because it's the only level I understand), `getMethodParent` is not an overridden method, so you're not call the methods "super", so the runtime uses a lookup mechanism and checks `ChildClass` and sees not `intro` method (or one which has been overridden), so it pass the call to the `super` directly.  If you overrode `intro` instead, then you'd need to supply `super`, otherwise it would continue to call itself (the child implementation).  Simple, right

Answer (score 5):

You can call and access it because you have inherited it. `super` is only needed for when you have overriden the method, but still want to access the parent's version of it.

Comment: (or you want to circumvent the overridden version for some reason )

Answer (score 0):

Java has specific rules for inheritance based on the visibility you define a method. Here you declare `intro()` with default or package visibility, so it is automatically available in the `ChildClass`. This rule is similar to how you don't have to specify `this` before every method call in a class.